# How to redirect based on date with nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

So, a client is running a promo at a url, where each successive day the url must be a different webpage. All the webpages are already existing, it just means we must put a temporary redirect on this url each day. To avoid having to do this manually each day, I am wondering if this kind of date conditional redirect is possible with nginx.

Here's what the route looks like now:

```
location /10-day-promo {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_pass      http://50.160.80.120:8000;
}
```

I need something like:

```
location /10-day-promo {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_read_timeout 300;

    if right_now >= start_date and right_now <= end_date then
      return proxy_pass      http://50.160.80.120:8000;
    end
}
```

I'm not too familiar with nginx syntax so it is just an example. Is this type of thing possible?

Comment: What kind of date pattern do you run the promos on?

Comment: @TarunLalwani How do you mean? It should just be a conditional chain for entire calendar days, no hours or minutes.

Answer (score 1):

`nginx` has a datetime variable and a regular expression engine, so it is certainly possible, just not very pretty if your datetime boundaries are in awkward places.

For example, 5th November to 14th November UTC inclusive could be represented as:

```
if ($time_iso8601 ~ ^2017-11-(0[5-9]|1[0-4]) ) { ... }
```

As an alternative, consider placing the regular expressions into a `map`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more. Also, there are language extensions available, e.g. Perl or Lua.

Comment: The brackets are a character class, which is used to specify a range. There is a [quick reference here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html). If you want a solution closer to your example, you may need to investigate Perl or Lua (which I cannot help you with).

Comment: This won't work because $time_iso8601 is specific to logging and may only be used in the log_format directive.

Comment: @jpswade `$time_iso8601` is in the http core module. It is not limited to the `log_format` directive. The above answer works just fine.

Comment: Hmm that’s weird, it didn’t work for me and I found documentation that stated that it only exists as part of the log format directive so I’m assuming there’s a version disparity.

Comment: [Documentation for the log module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) now states: `In the modern nginx versions variables $status (1.3.2, 1.2.2), $bytes_sent (1.3.8, 1.2.5), $connection (1.3.8, 1.2.5), $connection_requests (1.3.8, 1.2.5), $msec (1.3.9, 1.2.6), $request_time (1.3.9, 1.2.6), $pipe (1.3.12, 1.2.7), $request_length (1.3.12, 1.2.7), $time_iso8601 (1.3.12, 1.2.7), and $time_local (1.3.12, 1.2.7) are also available as common variables.`.